# In JetBrains IDE new terminal opens in $HOME folder instead of project root

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, zsh, jetbrains-ide

Happened on MacOS Monterey today, but it used to work correctly.

Just checked on Ubuntu machine: new terminal opens in Project root.
On my mac though, new terminal tab opens in `/Users/<UserName>` folder.

I think it might be connected to zsh settings, but not sure where to dig.

To be clear, here you can see my project settings:

[image: settings]

Clearly should open the project root, but opens `$HOME` folder instead.

I'll be glad to hear any suggestions...

Comment: which tool `JetBrains` or `VSC`

Comment: @rioV8 it happens in both JetBrains and VSC, which makes me think the problem is global and connected to zsh.

I usually use JetBrains IDEs though: Webstorm and Intellij Idea.

Comment: look at the arguments you can give the terminal programs, can you specify the start directory, if so then the tool is responsible of that directory

Answer (score 0):

So, i initially was right - it's not a problem of IDE. It's somewhere in zsh settings.

I reinstalled zsh, oh-my-zsh, all the plugins, reinstalled volta (node.js version management) and then found out that the initial behaviour of opening project path was working again.

I guess, problem is solved...